# translate xml to json in node.js

Tags: xml, json, node.js, saxparser

could you, please, point me to some working xml -> json translation library for node.js?

A SAX-styled would be preferable to get things done while the xml file is still receiving.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js

Answer (score 4):

You can try [xml2js](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js). I've tried it myself, but for really simple xml, so I'm not sure if it will work "while the xml file is still receiving".

Answer (score 0):

http://code.google.com/p/x2js 
But it working with DOM.